# Head (not face) detection and tracking in kinect depth maps

Tags: opencv, kinect, tracking, head, depth

I am looking for the best way to track human heads (not faces) in a stream of depth maps from the kinect using OpenCV. I want to use only depth data, no color info. Any ideas?
I've tried using Haar cascade classifiers for upper body provided in OpenCV but they do not give robust performance.
 Thanks

Comment: It would probably help if you could post some code showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: haar cascades are trained to detect faces in intensity images not distance. so yes, they wont work. however, you can train your own cascade on depth images using opencv. only catch is you need a ton of depth images with hand labelled face positions.

Comment: I am actually looking for a method that does not require any training. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions:

- For detection, with OpenNI you can use the HEAD_HANDS skeleton profile and use the position of the head with a threshold radius to isolate the head.
- The Microsoft Kinect SDK has [Face Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130970.aspx) which should help.
- Alternatively you can use this [Head Pose Estimation](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~gfanelli/head_pose/head_forest.html) by Gabriele Fanelli and his team.
  (this uses OpenNI and OpenCV)